# highcharts.NET Add Additional Data to datalabel

Tags: c#, highcharts

I am generating a pie chart using highcharts.NET which displays the heart rate zones used in a workout as a percentage. However, I would like the tooltip to display this value as a unit of time.

```
 zonesPercentage.ForEach(t => pieData.Add(new PieSeriesData
 {
    Name = t.Effort,
    Y = (double?)t.Percentage,
    Sliced = t.Effort.Equals("Threshold", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase),
    Selected = t.Effort.Equals("Threshold", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)
}));
```

The datalabel looks like the following...

```
 DataLabels = new PlotOptionsPieDataLabels
                  {
                     Enabled = false,
                     Format = "<b>{point.name}</b>: {point.percentage:.1f} %"
                  }
```

However, I would like to use a custom attribute so that my format can be something like...

```
"<b>{point.name}</b>: {point.customTimeAttribute}"
```

This is possible with Highcharts.js, but is it possible through it's .NET wrapper?

Comment: Using custom properties is not supported in Highcharts .NET wrapper yet.

Comment: Thanks @KamilKulig. Are there any plans to implement such a feature?

Comment: I have passed your case to our .NET developer and we are investigating this option. I hope that at the beginning of next week, we will have a demo .

Comment: @SebastianBochan As an interim step, I wonder if it is possible to add custom data once the chart has been rendered via javascript?

Comment: @DanielShillcock could you elaborate your question in more details? Im not sure what kind of scenerio you have in your mind

Comment: @SebastianBochan Ah, please disregard - I had a think and decided whatever I was thinking was a terrible idea :)

Comment: @DanielShillcock we developed a custom fields demo here -> http://dotnet.highcharts.com/downloads/CustomFieldsSample.zip. Let me know if you have any further questions.

Comment: @SebastianBochan This is exactly what I had in mind!

Comment: I added demo as an answer below. Thank you for the feedback! ;)

Comment: @SebastianBochan Is there any ETA on when highcharts will be updated with this change?

Comment: In the nuget service, there is the newest release (6.1.0.24) -> https://www.nuget.org/packages/Highsoft.Highcharts/

Comment: @SebastianBochan much appreciated! I've updated with an answer including a snippet from the example solution.

Comment: @DanielShillcock thanks! good job!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is available on Highcharts.net (Nuget package [Here](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Highsoft.Highcharts/)) 6.1.0.24 and later. Here is an example of how to implement a chart with additional data fields from an MVC controller.

```
 public ActionResult Index()
 {
    List<PieSeriesData> pieData = new List<PieSeriesData>();

    pieData.Add(new PieSeriesData { Name = "FireFox", Y = 45.0 });
    pieData.Add(new PieSeriesData { Name = "IE", Y = 26.8 });
    pieData.Add(new PieSeriesData { Name = "Chrome", Y = 12.8, Sliced = true, Selected = true });
    pieData.Add(new PieSeriesData { Name = "Safari", Y = 8.5 });
    pieData.Add(new PieSeriesData { Name = "Opera", Y = 6.2 });
    pieData.Add(new PieSeriesData { Name = "Others", Y = 0.7 });

    //// Add additional data fields to the first PieSeriesData object.
    pieData[0].CustomFields.Add("expected", 37);
    pieData[0].CustomFields.Add("result", "success!");

    ViewData["pieData"] = pieData;

    return View();
}
```

From here, initialise the chart in your view as normal. I haven't provided the code for this as it can be quite extensive.

The good people at Highcharts have provided an example solution demonstrating how to use additional custom data fields. Link [here](http://dotnet.highcharts.com/downloads/CustomFieldsSample.zip).

Answer (score 2):

We developed a custom fields demo here -> http://dotnet.highcharts.com/downloads/CustomFieldsSample.zip.